# Exception thrown when stubbing mocked `ISession` object

Tags: c#, nhibernate, rhino-mocks

I have the following code where I try to stub `ISession.Query<UnitModel>()`.

```
var unitList = new List<UnitModel>()
            {
                new UnitModel(){Name = "meters", Symbol="m"},
                new UnitModel(){Name="grams", Symbol="g"}
            };

MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISession>().Stub(x => x.Query<UnitModel>()).Return(unitList.AsQueryable<UnitModel>());
```

When running, this throws the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[[MIB.DomainModels.UnitModel, MIB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' doesn't match the return type 'NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor' for method 'ISession.GetSessionImplementation();'
```

What am I doing wrong here? How should I go about stubbing `ISession.Query<UnitModel>()`?

NHibernate 3.3.0.4000

Edit:
`UnitModel` class:

```
public class UnitModel
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your UnitModel class up here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mocking `ISession` is usually costly and painful.

`Query<T>`, in particular, is an extension method that calls `ISession.GetSessionImplementation()` internally, so you'd have to mock that to work with it (which is non-trivial and actually ties you to a specific implementation detail)

There are two better alternatives:

1. Implement a repository interface that has an implementation backed by the NHibernate session, and can be easily mocked

   - Pros: powerful, no limitations
   - Cons: you might find yourself limited by your own abstraction or reinventing the wheel when you need access to specific NH features
2. Use an in-memory or clean DB for testing

   - Pros: much less work to setup, you have access to all NH features
   - Cons: if you use a different DB engine, some queries might have a different behavior.

Unless you are already using repositories, my advice is to go with #2.

Comment: I tried to go with 1, but along the way I realized that I need quite a lot of different queries in my app and my repository interface started looking like `ISession` itself. Then I went to 2. As I have NCrunch, even working with MSSQLServer 2005, there is virtually no time lost for tests.

Answer (score 0):

Implement ISessionImplementor in your UnitModel class, VisualStudio should then warn you about missing methods... Although I'm not sure it'll help too much as ISessionImplementor is an internal interface which I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be using!